# Find records having at least one element of a given array in an array column

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I use PG's array type to store some integers in a `Order` table:

```
Order
id: 1
array_column: [1, 2, 3]

id: 2
array_column: [3, 4, 5]
```

And I'd like to have a query returning all Orders having at least one element of a given array (let's say `[3]`) in `array_column`.

So for `[3]`, it should return both orders since they both have 3 in array_column. For `[4, 5]`, it should only return the second order since the first one doesn't have any element in common, and for `[9, 10, 49]`, it shouldn't return anything.

How can I achieve this with ActiveRecord ? If it's not feasible, how can I do this using a plain SQL query ?

Comment: I will suggest you to add tag `ruby` or `ruby-on-rails` to have more attention on your question

Comment: What is datatype of `array_column` in your table?